# No tea. No coffee. No water

Tags: riddle, knowledge, anagram

Fr Owen More had left the exclusive Dublin Temperance Society meeting and was relieved to be sitting down in the living room of Mrs. Philippa Glass. She brought him a

> wee fat-free jam oat scone

Then the conversation went:
Philippa - Will you have tea?
Fr Owen – No tea.
Philippa - Will you have coffee?
Fr Owen – No coffee.
Philippa - Will you have whiskey and water?
Fr Owen – No water.
So Philippa poured him a glass of which brand of whiskey?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The brand is:

> Jameson

Because:

> When you remove the letters of the words tea, coffee and water from 'wee fat-free jam oat scone' you are left with the letters E, J, M, A, S, O and N, with which you can form the whiskey brand 'Jameson'

Comment: Very fast - well done :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out if there's something more in the choice of names?  Fr Owen More looks like a possible anagram, though I haven't found a particularly apt one.  And Philippa Glass appears to be implying a female version of composer Philip Glass, but it's more likely just because it sounds like "Fill up a glass".  Not sure about the Friar though.  Maybe I'm just reading too much into it.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Think you are reading too much into it. Fr Owen More = Throw in More. Phillippa Glass = Fill up a glass. Just two people who love a drink.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman. "Fr" is usually an abbreviation of "Father", not "Friar".

Answer (score 2):

The whiskey is

> Jameson's
>  I read over *wee fat-free jam oat scone* giving it different accents in my head, & imagining an Irish accent, it sounded like a 'wee ?? of jameson' or maybe 'a whiff of jamesons'